# Compare two list items together

Tags: c#, linq, compare

I have an ObservableCollection of researchers.
Researchers who are staff members supervise students.
Researchers who are students have a supervisor_id field.
Everyone researcher has an id field.

I want to be able to count the number of supervisions a staff member has.
So how do I use LINQ to go through every item and find if the supervisor field is equal to an ID field of a staff member?

Staff members have a supervisor_id field, but it is set to 0 since they don't have supervisors.

Thanks in advance.

Ok I have these two in an Researcher class. I have more fields than this but that isn't important.

```
 public int id { get; set; }
 public int supervisor_id { get; set; }
```

I then have a SQL function which grabs all the info I need from a database.

Here is a picture of the database: [image: Database]

So now I want to be able to count how many supervisions a staff member has.

Comment: I have no idea how to even go about it. From what I can tell, LINQ will just assess each item at a time.

Comment: can you present your schema

Comment: How can you store reasearcher name and id in ObservableCollection?

Comment: SQL schema or C# class design please!

Comment: `So now I want to be able to count how many supervisions a staff member has.` I think it's one to one mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will return you a dictionary that has a supervisor's id followed by the count of their students assuming researchers is your collection:

```
var supervisorStudents = researchers.Where(r => r.supervisor_id == 0).
            ToDictionary(supervisor => supervisor.id, supervisor => 
                researchers.Where(student => student.supervisor_id == supervisor.id).Select(student => student.id).Count());
```